# Solving complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

How do i further solve the following complex equation:

$$ z\cdot  \bar{z} + z + \bar{z} + i\cdot z - \overline{i \cdot z} = 9 + 4i $$
$$ a^{2} - b^{2} + 2a - 2b = 9 + 4i$$

How do i solve from here on ?

Comment: Do you mean $z\bar{z}+z+\bar{z}+iz-\overline{iz}=9+4i$?

Comment: Yes my latex is bad i didnt know how to do that negate sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the equation
$$z\bar{z}+z+\bar{z}+iz-\overline{iz}=9+4i,$$
we can proceed much as you did. Let $z=a+ib$.

Then $z\bar{z}=(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2+b^2$.

We have $iz=-b+ia$, so its conjugate is $-b-ia$. Our expression is therefore equal to
$$a^2+b^2+(a+ib)+(a-ib)+(-b+ia)-(-b-ia),$$
which simplifies to $a^2+b^2+2a+2ia$.

This is $9+4i$ precisely if the imaginary parts match **and** the real parts match.  We end up with the equations $2a=4$ and $a^2+b^2+2a=9$. Now $a$ and then $b$ are easy to find.

Comment: To finish the job, a = 2 and b = 1 :)

Comment: @Martin: Well, there is also $b=-1$.

Comment: So $$ 2ai = 4i, a^{2} + b^{2} + 2a = 9 $$ Would then a = 2i and i put this a in to $$ a^2{2} + b^{2} + 2a = 9  $$ to solve for b ?

Comment: @kellax: I wrote $2a=4$. If you like, you can write $2ai=4i$ and divide both sides by $i$, getting $2a=4$. Then $a=2$. Now because $a^2+b^2+2a=9$, we have $2^2+b^2+4=9$, so $b^2=1$, and therefore $b=\pm 1$.

Comment: One thing i dont understand is the last part $$ -\overline{iz} $$ wouldnt that equal $$ - i \cdot (a - bi) == - (ai + b) $$

Comment: @kellax: With your way of calculating, we get $-\overline{iz}=-(\bar{i})(\overline{a+bi})=-(-i)(a-bi)=b+ai$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: the real part of both hands must be equal: $$z\bar z + z+\bar z = 9.$$
The imaginary part of both hands must be equal: $$i(z+\bar z)=4i.$$

So $z$ and $\bar z$ are two numbers; their sum is $4$ and their product is $9-4=5$. So they satisfy
$$ z^2 - 4z + 5 = 0.$$
This you can solve.